# What is the significance of the recurring dancing bear?

Tags: hamatora

In Hamatora, there's a dancing animal - seems to be a bear - that appears (almost) every episode.

[image: The dancing bear seen in the background]

Besides appearing in the background dancing or doing other things that draw attention to him, his figure also appears in certain other circumstances. For instance, in the first episode we see some stickers of him.

[image: Bear stickers]

**What is the significance of this dancing bear? And does he have a name?**

Answer (score 4):

I think it's not a bear, it's a tiger (Tora). And according to [wiki](http://hamatora.wikia.com/wiki/Tanker-Kun) his name is Tanker-kun.

For now it's some kind of mascot (no further details), because Hamatora (ハマトラ) means "Beach Tiger". And Tanker-kun always use sailor suit, so for now we can assume he's mascot of Hamatora.